# My dataframe returns 0 rows, yet when I use filters on excel spreadsheet the rows are displayed

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

My dataframe is not returning the rows, as per date filter, but when I open the same file in excel spreadsheet and use filters, I am able to retrieve the data. What am I doing wrong?

Applications for 2018 that came in 2017

```
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df4 = pd.read_csv('report1547464798320.csv')  

#displaying all the 2018 applications
df4['Date Applied'] = pd.to_datetime(df4['Date Applied'])

start_date = '2017-01-01'
end_date = '2017-12-31'

mask = (df4['Date Applied'] >= start_date) & (df4['Date Applied'] <= end_date)

df4 = df4.loc[mask]
```

I am supposed to get 1300+ records from this execution.

Comment: We need to see some sample data and the values you're filtering against. In other words, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't think pandas will do implicit conversion of the datetime to a string for your comparison but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Can you share the csv file (partial)? Up to Gdrive and share the link.

Comment: Small recommendation: when you quote code, format it using the {} button so it's shown as a code snippet, which makes it easier to read.

Comment: I think @roganjosh is right, the strings are not implicitly converted to datetime objects. You could use `start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d")`. Using datetime objects  in the filter instead of the strings should work

Comment: Hi @AndreAraujo https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MOb7O-EYV6U639rWTSZhnvKVSZc9rf0x/view?usp=sharing                          Ascurion that 'datetime' is it not supposed to be variable, cause now I'm unsure what I would need to assign to it, apologies guys I'm still new to Pandas coming from Java stream.

Comment: @msingathimajola Check my answer. A good approach is parse the date first. The safe comparison should between dates variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the dates first in order to guarantee:

```
import dateutil as du

start_date = du.parser.parse('2017-01-01', dayfirst=False)
end_date = du.parser.parse('2017-12-31', dayfirst=False)
```

The parameter dayfirst means:

- Whether to interpret the first value in an ambiguous 3-integer date (e.g. 01/05/09) as the day (True) or month (False). If yearfirst is set to True, this distinguishes between YDM and YMD. Default is False.

In this case was optional because the default is False, but just to show you that you can distinguishes between YDM and YMD.

Here is the docs about: [link](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks @Andre I tried out your suggested solution, and this seems to offer a more accurate list of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issues on this file, the only thing I did was copy the code I was using for a file where the date range was for Jan 2018- Dec 2018 which was working fine, and pasted on this file, with the date range as above, not sure what could've been the problem with my first copy and paste. However thanks for the help from everyone who contributed